# How to calculate the probability that the median exceeds a certain value?

Tags: density-function, median

Given the pdf $f(x)=\begin{cases}2x&\text{0<x<1}\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. What is the probability that the sample median based on a random sample of size 3 drawn from the distribution with pdf f(x) exceeds 1/2?

Here, although I can calculate the value of the median by integrating f(x) from $0$ to median=m(say) and then equating it to $1/2$. The value for median came $1/\sqrt2$. But I don't know how to find the probability for the median now.

Comment: Please add the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag. The population median that you found is a constant. Question asks for the sample median which is random. Do you know order statistics?

Comment: Yes I do know order statistics.

Comment: That would be the 2nd value of the sample.

Comment: I think you meant this, but you want the second-largest/smallest value. Consider the data set $\{2,3,1\}$. The median is 2, not 3.

Comment: Yes. After ordering the sample either in increasing or decreasing order, the median would be the middlemost value i.e. the second-largest in this case.

Comment: Then which order statistic is of interest to this problem?

Comment: Yes that would be $X_{(2)}$

Comment: Correct! Do you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: In an answer to a related question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86120/919 I provide a formula for the solution: see the section immediately preceding "Asymptotic Results."

Comment: So that means I need to calculate $P(X_{(2)}>1/2)$.

Comment: @Azka that’s exactly what you have to do.

Answer (score 5):

Alexander Pope wrote "A little learning is a dangerous thing, ..." but great learnings (as in BruceET's answer and in the link posted by whuber) can create unneeded diversions in solving little problems.

We have three independent random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ for which we readily can compute that $P(X_i < \frac 12) = \frac 14$ and $P(X_i > \frac 12) = \frac 34$. We are asked for the probability that at least two of the $X_i$ exceed $\frac 12$. Well, the probability that all three exceed $\frac 12$ is $\left(\frac 34\right)^3 = \frac{27}{64}$ while the probability that exactly two of the $X_i$ exceed $\frac 34$ is $3\times \frac 14\times \left(\frac 34\right)^2 = \frac{27}{64}$, making the desired probability $\frac{27}{32} = 0.84375$, no muss, no fuss, no Beta distributions or  calculating the pdf of $X_{(2)}$ or simulations in R yielding three digits of accuracy with a million trials.

Comment: I’ve changed to an upvote. This is an interesting take on the problem, though I do think the purpose of this homework was to use order statistics. @Azka do you get how to work with the order statistic $X_{(2)}$?

Comment: @Dave Yes I did work out through the order statistics method and got my answer. Thanks for your help. I understood the concept now.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate I think your method is quite interesting too just like Dave said. Its much easier on the computation part. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: You have the math in Comments from @Dave and @whuber' link.
The initial probability distribution is a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Order_statistics), specifically $\mathsf{Beta}(2,1).$ Maybe you can match
your distribution for $H=X_{(2)}$ to results in the following simulation in R, using
a million samples of size $n = 3.$ [With a million iterations you
can expect 2, maybe 3, decimal places of accuracy.]

```
set.seed(928)
h = replicate(10^6, median(rbeta(3, 2, 1)))
mean(h > .5)
[1] 0.843916       # aprx P(H > .5)
2*sd(h>.5)/10^3
[1] 0.0007258703   # 95% margin of sim err for P(H > .5)
27/32
[1] 0.84375        # exact P(H > .5)   
mean(h)
[1] 0.685836
hist(h, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
abline(v = .5, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]